# Is there anyway to check if someone has a bitcoin wallet?

Tags: wallet-recovery, paper-wallet, e-wallet

My son passed away years ago and it has been brought to my attention he may have bought a sum of bitcoin years ago.
Can someone please tell me how I can check to see if his wallet is still active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to look through his computers for Bitcoin software or files generally called wallet.dat.

In his papers, you're looking for anything labeled "Paper Wallet", or with QR Codes or long hex-numbers.

Good luck.

Comment: Perhaps you should also mention that coins could be stored on exchanges or e-wallets.

Comment: @VickiBidwell if you have access to his email accounts, you should also try searching them for any evidence of accounts on an exchange or e-wallet (as Pieter mentioned). I'm sorry for your loss, best of luck on your search.